# How to create a recursive pyramid function?

Tags: python, recursion

I do need to create two recursive functions in Python. the first function should create a pyramid with a given parameter `n`. for example `pyramid(3)` should have the following output

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

I came up with the following function:

```
def pyramid(n, i=0):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        print(" "*(n-1) +"*"*(2*i+1)+ " "*(n-1))
        return pyramid(n-1, i+1)
```

Now I do need to create a second recursive function `pyramid_seq` with 2 parameters `n,k` what prints a sequence of pyramids in with height of `n`. for example `pyramid_seq(3,4)` should have the following output:

```
  *    *    *    *
 ***  ***  ***  ***
********************
```

Answer (score 2):

Add another parameter to your function (notice the changes in the recursive call) that determines how many times you should print every line. This will create the desired effect.

```
def pyramid(n, k, i=0):

    if n == 0:
        return 0

    else:
        print(k*(" "*(n-1) +"*"*(2*i+1)+ " "*(n-1)))
        return pyramid(n-1, k, i+1)
```

Output for `pyramid(4, 6)`:

```
   *      *      *      *      *      *   
  ***    ***    ***    ***    ***    ***  
 *****  *****  *****  *****  *****  ***** 
******************************************
```

Comment: I was wondering how could we achieve the same sequence of pyramids with different heights?

Comment: @alamshahbaz16497 do you mean a pyramid with (for example) 5 levels? If that's what you meant, then all you need to do is change the parameter 'n', which controls how many levels each pyramid will have. If you meant something else, please elaborate because I didn't understand you

Comment: No I meant how do we print pyramids with different heights in the sequence. Example: pyramid(2, 3, 5, 8) so the first pyramid would be of height 2 then the second would ve 3 and so on.

Comment: @alamshahbaz16497 I think a recursive solution is not the fitting solution to your problem, but of course it can be forced

Answer (score 1):

If you want to properly leverage the power of recursion, your function should return their result as data and the printing part should be separate.  This will allow you to reuse a previously defined function to produces new results from it:

```
def pyramid(h):
    if h==1: return ["*"]
    return [" "+p+" " for p in pyramid(h-1)]+["*"*(2*h-1)]
```

The function returns an array of lines (strings) that you can print or reuse for something else:

```
print(*pyramid(5),sep="\n")

    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
```

Because you now have a function that generates a pyramid as a list of lines, you can reuse it to concatenate its result to form a series of pyramids without reinventing the wheel:

```
def pyramids(h,w):
    return [p*w for p in pyramid(h)]


print(*pyramids(4,6),sep="\n")

   *      *      *      *      *      *   
  ***    ***    ***    ***    ***    ***  
 *****  *****  *****  *****  *****  ***** 
******************************************
```

If your second function also needs to be recursive, you can still reuse the first one to build it:

```
def pyramids(h,w):
    if w == 1: return pyramid(h)
    return [ ps+p for ps,p in zip(pyramids(h,w-1),pyramid(h)) ]
```